# If statement to set values, not working as expected

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to apply colour to some rows of data, which is done using the `colswitch` variable below. How it works in the software is irrelevant so I've just included a snippet. It's part of a loop that applies various logic to the data. Edited to add more code...

The rules I'd like it to follow are below, unfortunately, everything goes red, unless I remove the lines with the if statements, then it correctly leaves things alone unless status is `Open`.

`dateadded` is a variable containing a datetime value. At least one of these is older than 7 days.

`objstatus = Open` - set `colswitch` to yellow

`objstatus = Third Party or Waiting for reply, unless older than 7 days` - set `colswitch` to blue

`objstatus = >7 days after 'date_added'` - set `colswitch` to red

The code:

```
        <%
            if DispLastUpd_val = "Y" then 
                IF DBType = "Access" then response.write "<TD bgcolor='" & bghicol & "'><font face='" & stanfont & "' size='" & textsizenorm & "' color='" & menhcol & "'><a href='DispOpenCalls.asp?Type=" & ListType & "&sortit=Max(event_dateadded)&sortorder=" & SortOrder & "&callstat=" & request.querystring("callstat") & "&stat=" & request.querystring("stat")& "'>Last Update</a></font></TD>"
                IF DBType = "SQL" then response.write "<TD bgcolor='" & bghicol & "'><font face='" & stanfont & "' size='" & textsizenorm & "' color='" & menhcol & "'><a href='DispOpenCalls.asp?Type=" & ListType & "&sortit=LastEvt&sortorder=" & SortOrder & "&callstat=" & request.querystring("callstat") & "&stat=" & request.querystring("stat")& "'>Last Update</a></font></TD>"
            end if
            if DispToFix_val = "Y" then 
                if SLAmonitor = 0 then 
                    IF DBType = "Access" then response.write "<TD bgcolor='" & bghicol & "'><font face='" & stanfont & "' size='" & textsizenorm & "' color='" & menhcol & "'><a href='DispOpenCalls.asp?Type=" & ListType & "&sortit=(DateDiff({sq}h{sq},call_dateadded,Now())-PRIORITY_FIXHOURS)&sortorder=" & SortOrder & "&callstat=" & request.querystring("callstat") & "&stat=" & request.querystring("stat")& "'>To Fix</a></font></TD>"
                    IF DBType = "SQL" then response.write "<TD bgcolor='" & bghicol & "'><font face='" & stanfont & "' size='" & textsizenorm & "' color='" & menhcol & "'><a href='DispOpenCalls.asp?Type=" & ListType & "&sortit=(DateDiff(hh,call_dateadded,getdate())-PRIORITY_FIXHOURS)&sortorder=" & SortOrder & "&callstat=" & request.querystring("callstat") & "&stat=" & request.querystring("stat")& "'>To Fix</a></font></TD>"
                end if
                if SLAmonitor = 1 then 
                    response.write "<TD bgcolor='" & bghicol & "'><font face='" & stanfont & "' size='" & textsizenorm & "' color='" & menhcol & "'><a href='DispOpenCalls.asp?Type=" & ListType & "&sortit=((sla_callhours - sla_defhours)-PRIORITY_FIXHOURS)&sortorder=" & SortOrder & "&callstat=" & request.querystring("callstat") & "&stat=" & request.querystring("stat")& "'>To Fix</a></font></TD>"
                end if
            end if

        colswitch = LISTCOL1
        Do Until myset.EOF
            if colswitch = LISTCOL1 then colswitch = LISTCOL2 else colswitch = LISTCOL1 
    '
    '
    'MY CODE IS BELOW
        if objstatus = "Open" then colswitch = "yellow" 'this works
        calldays = DateDiff("d",dateadded,now())  
        if calldays > 7 then colswitch = "red"  'this is where it breaks
        if objstatus = "Third Party" or objstatus = "Waiting for Reply") and (calldays < 7) then colswitch = "blue" 

         '
         '
         ' end of my code
'

    objslastat = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/blanksla.gif'>"
    masticon = ""
    urgicon = ""
    probicon = ""
    changeicon = ""
    atticon = ""

    if SLAmonitor = 0 then
        If objCallTime => objtimeesc and objstatus = "Open" then objslastat = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/Button_sla_esc.gif' title='Exceeds Response Escalation time'>"
        If objCallTime => objtimesla and objstatus = "Open" then objslastat = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/Button_sla.gif'  title='Exceeds Response time'>" 
        If objCallTime => objtimefixesc and objstatus <> "Closed" then objslastat = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/Button_fix_esc.gif' title='Exceeds Resolve Escalation time'>"
        If objCallTime => objtimefix and objstatus <> "Closed" then objslastat = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/Button_fix.gif' title='Exceeds Resolve time'>"
    end if

    if SLAmonitor = 1 then
        If objsla = "ESC" and objstatus = "Open" then objslastat = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/Button_sla_esc.gif'  title='Exceeds Response Escalation time'>"
        If objsla = "RES" and objstatus = "Open" then objslastat = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/Button_sla.gif'  title='Exceeds Response time'>" 
        If objsla = "ESF" and objstatus <> "Closed" then objslastat = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/Button_fix_esc.gif' title='Exceeds Resolve Escalation time'>"
        If objsla = "FIX" and objstatus <> "Closed" then objslastat = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/Button_fix.gif' title='Exceeds Resolve time'>"
    End if

    if objmastcallcode > 0 then masticon = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/linked.gif' title='Linked " & tgencallterm & " - Master " & objMastCallCode & "'>"   
    if objmastcall = "Y" then masticon = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/linkedm.gif' title='Master " & tgencallterm & "'>" 

    if objurg = "T" then urgicon = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/urgent.gif' title='Urgent'>" 
    if objurguser = "T" then urgicon = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/urgent.gif' title='Urgent'>" 

    if objki = "T" then probicon = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/prob.gif' title='Problem " & tgencallterm & "'>" 

    if objnochange > 0 then changeicon = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/change.gif' title='" & tchangetext & "'>" 

    if objnoatt > 0 then atticon = "<img border='0' src='../IMAGES/attachment.gif' title='Attachments'>" 

    ' This bit avoids issue with Team Calls when using Next / Prev
    if request.querystring("type") = "Team" then qry = ""

        Response.Write "<TR><TD nowrap bgcolor='" & colswitch & "'>" & urgicon & "</TD>"
        Response.Write "<TD nowrap bgcolor='" & colswitch & "'>" & atticon & "</TD>"
        Response.Write "<TD nowrap bgcolor='" & colswitch & "'><a href='UpdateCall.asp?inp_call_id=" & objcallcode & "&qry=" & qry & "'><font face='" & stanfont & "' size='" & textsizelist & "' color='" & menicol & "'>" & objcallcode & "</font></TD><TD bgcolor='" & colswitch & "'><font face='" & stanfont & "' size='" & textsizelist & "' color='" & menicol & "'>" & objslastat & "</font></TD>"
        response.write "<TD bgcolor='" & colswitch & "'>" & masticon & "</font></TD>"
        response.write "<TD bgcolor='" & colswitch & "'>" & probicon & "</font></TD>"
        response.write "<TD bgcolor='" & colswitch & "'>" & changeicon & "</font></TD>"

        ' Loop through data results
        For x = 0 to ColCount
        response.write "<TD " & ColWrap(x) & " bgcolor='" & colswitch & "'><font face='" & stanfont & "' size='" & textsizelist & "' color='" & menicol & "'>" 
        if isdate(ColResults(x)) then response.write FmtDateDisp(ColResults(x)) else response.write ColResults(x)
        response.write "</font></TD>"
    Next

        if DispLastUpd_val = "Y" then response.write "<TD nowrap bgcolor='" & colswitch & "'><font face='" & stanfont & "' size='" & textsizelist & "' color='" & menicol & "'>" & FmtDateDisp(objLastEvt) & " (" & DateDiff("d",objLastEvt ,now()) & " Days)</font></TD>"

        if DispToFix_val = "Y" then 
            if objtimefix = "" or isnull(objtimefix) then objtimefix = 0
            if objCallTime= "" or isnull(objCallTime) then objCallTime= 0
            response.write "<TD nowrap align='right' bgcolor='" & colswitch & "'><font face='" & stanfont & "' size='" & textsizelist & "' color='" & menicol & "'>" & formatnumber(objtimefix - objCallTime,2) &  " Hrs</font></TD></TR>"
        end if

        colswitch = ocolswitch
        myset.MoveNext   

 Loop 
%>
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: try to comment my answer. then try to run it. if error still exist then the error must be in your loop

Comment: The error only happens with the `elseif` x2 statements. If i change those back to `if` & remove the `endif`, it works but doesn't correctly assign the colours.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not so clear to me.

try to replace your code with this:

```
if objstatus = "Open" then colswitch = "yellow"
calldays = DateDiff("d",dateadded,now())  
elseif calldays > 7 then colswitch = "red"
elseif (objstatus = "Third Party" or objstatus = "Waiting for Reply") and (calldays < 7) then colswitch = "blue" 
end if
```

If any thing is wrong just inform me.

Comment: Nope it still gave me the expected loop error even with the end if

Comment: @jbab8 can you show you all code. SO that i can catch up why it is have an error like that. Edit your question with that

Comment: The code is over 500 lines long so I can't include all of it. I will edit with some other relevant information though

Comment: @jbab8 ahaha not really all your code. just code that connects to your problem etc. ahaha